# Is it possible to sum a row from a table to a row to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables made like so:

| NickName | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Player 1 | 15 |
| Player 2 | 8 |

| NickName | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Player 1 | 33 |
| Player 2 | 22 |

and I need to get this table:

| NickName | Points |
| --- | --- |
| Player 1 | 48 |
| Player 2 | 30 |

Is it possible to do such thing using a single query in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the two tables and perform an aggregation on the Points column using the `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT NickName, SUM(Points) as Points
FROM (
  SELECT NickName, Points FROM table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NickName, Points FROM table2
) as combined_tables
GROUP BY NickName;
```

db<>fiddle [output](https://dbfiddle.uk/DJyphYGY)

Comment: You can use `*` in the select list of both tables.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal design would be to have the data in the same table with a 3rd column defining whatever it is that currently separates your data (i.e. event/game etc).  This would allow you to select the data either separately or aggregate.

E.g.

SELECT NickName, Points from mytable WHERE eventID = 1

or

SELECT NickName, SUM(Points) from mytable GROUP BY NickName